# Compile error with "this" keyword in a struct constructor? - C++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I have the following:

```
int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        unsigned char x, y;

        A(unsigned char x, unsigned char y)
        {
            this.x = x; // Error: expression must have class type.
            thix.y = y; // Error: expression must have class type.
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

How do I properly refer to the `x` and `y` variables of the `struct A` and not the `x` and `y` variables of the constructor parameters of `A`?

Thank you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No constructors even for structs?

Comment: `this` is always pointer. Dereference it using `this->` or `(*this).`.

Comment: @Hatefiend The `C` language has no constructors, no destructors, no member functions, etc.  That's why the `C` tag was removed.

Comment: Oh ok. I knew `C` had `struct` so I thought the question would be somewhat relevant. Sorry.

Comment: Rename the parameters, which avoids the need to use the `this->` notation.  Or rename member variables.  Some people prefix member variables with "m_" other people add a suffix of "_".

Comment: @Hatefiend: there are occasionally questions that are relevant across C and C++, but they are relatively few and far between.  You're likely to be better off choosing one or the other language (by the sounds of it, C++ for you) than to dual-tag.  Dual-tagging annoys the denizens of both language tags when it is inappropriate, which is a lot of the time.  If you're not sure, choose one, not two, language tags.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`this` is a pointer, so you need to dereference it:

```
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
```

It doesn't matter if it's a `struct` or `class`, it's a pointer in both cases.  The only different between the two is that `struct` members are `public` by default, while `class` members are `private` by default.

Also, it's not a good idea to define a `struct` or `class` inside of a function.  Do it at global scope instead.

Comment: So.... in a class constructor I can use `this.VARIABLE_NAME_HERE` but with `struct` I must use a pointer symbol `->` ?

Comment: In C++, this is always a pointer, in a class as well as a struct.

Comment: Ah I see. So the format `this.variable` makes no sense in C++?

Comment: @Hatefiend Correct.  It's a pointer, not a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: @Hatefiend: to be pedantic, the `this` is a pointer the present instance of the class or struct.